# Difficulty calculating a distribution of values in an answer set.

Tags: normal-distribution, average

I'm running a questionnaire where respondents answer questions which are scored 1-5.

The below shows how many people answered each a question (left column) with the associated answer (5,4,3,2,1).

Is there any method by which I can reduce a single questions distribution of values (such as question 0's 11,12,1,0,1 answers) as a single value? For example between 0 and 1?

```
Answer   5.    4.    3.    2.    1.
Q 0 :   11    12     1     0     1
Q 1 :   12    12     0     1     0
Q 2 :    6     7     5     5     2
Q 3 :    3     3     5    11     3
Q 4 :    1    13     5     3     3
Q 5 :    4     3     4    10     4
Q 6 :    3     5     7     6     4
Q 7 :    0     3     7     7     8
Q 8 :    0     0     3     6    16
Q 9 :    6    12     2     4     1
Q 10 :   14    11     0     0     0
Q 11 :    8    12     3     1     1
Q 12 :    7     5     3     6     4
Q 13 :    5    10     5     3     2
Q 14 :    2     5     8     6     4
Q 15 :    7    10     8     0     0
Q 16 :   13    11     1     0     0
Q 17 :    4    14     6     0     1
Q 18 :    2     5     5     7     6
Q 19 :    0     4     4    11     6
Q 20 :    3    12     8     2     0
```

Comment: If you know that for each question, the # of people that answered in a specific category is $< (10)^n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ then you can devote $n$ decimal places to each such response.  For example, assuming that no question has a score $> 99$ for any category, then Q0 could be expressed as $0.1112010001$.

Comment: Re previous comment, working with decimals risks rounding errors.  It is better to work with large integers.  I know that Java has the BigInteger class, and I presume that similar facilities are available in (for example) C or Python.  Under this strategy, Q0 could be expressed as the large integer $1112010001.$

Comment: @user2661923, thank you. However this is a little (a lot) over my head. In the case that _all_ respondents answered `1`, I would expect a zero or close to zero value. And if _all_ respondents answered `5`, I would expect a 1 or close to 1 value.

Comment: What you have described is routinely do-able using my BigInteger (et al) strategy; however it requires the services of a professional programmer.  In effect, in order to avoid any risk of rounding error, this reduces to a programming problem, rather than a math problem.  For example, assume that you attach a weight of $(1)$ for a "1", $(5)$ for a "5", and so on.  Further assume that for a specific question, you had exactly $t$ respondents.  ...see next comment

Comment: If they each scored a $5$, you would have a max score of $(5t)$.  If they each scored a $(1)$ then you would have a min score of $(t)$.  So, convert the score of $(5t)$ to a score of $(1)$, and convert the score of $(t)$ to a score of $(0)$.  One **arbitrary** approach here, is $$\frac{S - t}{4t}$$ where $S$ is sum of the $t$ scores.

Comment: Re previous comments, it requires that you make some **arbitrary** value judgements of the relative merits for each of the scores of "1", "2", ..., "5".  For example, is a score of "5" **really** worth $5$ times as much as a score of "1"?  Is a score of "2" worth $2$ times as much as a score of "1"?